# Generating different object name with for loop

Tags: java

I need to generate IDs or the object name.

```
public String[] getID(){

    String[] tempArray;

    for(int x=0; x<staffNum;x++){
        String temp = ("Att" + [x]);
        tempArray += temp;
        }
    return tempArray;
    }
```

so the for loop should run and add the iteration number with att.
then that should go to an array.
But the + is the problem
its saying Syntax error on token +
How to I generate my IDs, please?

Comment: `String temp = "Att" + x; tempArray[x] = temp;` Also need to initialize the array so `String[] tempArray = new String[staffNum];`

Comment: This code is wrong at many points. Consider reading some Java basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want to do is this:

```
public String[] getID(){
    // Create an array of String of length staffNum
    String[] tempArray = new String[staffNum];
    for(int x = 0; x < staffNum; x++){
        // Affect the value Att[x] to each element of my array
        tempArray[x] = String.format("Att[%d]", x);
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line with

```
String temp = ("Att" + Integer.toString(x));
```

Comment: There are many problems with his code, although this is one of them, it does not solve all of them.

Comment: I just solved his compile time error which he is getting right now. Not Others

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is off.
Also you have to initialize the array.
The naming of the method isn't ideal.

```
//you're getting more than one id so indicate in method name
    public String[] getIds(){
            //initialize array
            String[] tempArray = new String[staffNum];
            //use i for indexes
            for(int i=0; i<staffNum; i++){
                //append the int onto the String
                String tempString = ("Att" + i);
            //set the array element
                tempArray[i] = tempString;
            }
        return tempArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize the array for size `staffNum`.
2. In the loop :

   - use `temp = "Att" + x`
   - Use `tempArray[x]= temp;`